# Free software for creating rich interactive HTML user manuals?

Tags: gratis, software-development

I need some free software to help me easily produce an interactive - searchable/collapsible HTML manual for a software product. It is mostly with educational purposes.

Also, I am looking on some background on designing manuals in software development, a book on the subject, or a series of nice articles on the history of software manuals, file formats, tools, goals, templates etc. would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/)? It takes RST files and converts them into HTML and PDF, we use it to generate all the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/index.html) for GeoServer, it's easy to keep it in version control and automatically generate it with new builds.

The home page highlights these features:

> Output formats: HTML (including Windows HTML Help), LaTeX (for
> printable PDF versions), ePub, Texinfo, manual pages, plain text
>
> Extensive cross-references: semantic markup and automatic links for
> functions, classes, citations, glossary terms and similar pieces of
> information
>
> Hierarchical structure: easy definition of a document
> tree, with automatic links to siblings, parents and children
>
> Automatic
> indices: general index as well as a language-specific module indices
>
> Code handling: automatic highlighting using the Pygments highlighter
>
> Extensions: automatic testing of code snippets, inclusion of
> docstrings from Python modules (API docs), and more Contributed
> extensions: more than 50 extensions contributed by users in a second
> repository; most of them installable from PyPI

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of really great options but most of the good ones aren't free. My first recommendation is to use an opensource Wiki app. They allow you to document the software and add to the docs as support questions come in.They are designed to be searchable, your company can host one instance with multiple products,and generally, most wikis provide an easy to use interface. Try looking at MediaWiki, Wiki.js, or DokuWiki, Or, search for others and try the out.

Good luck. Hope you find something that works.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [HeVeA](http://hevea.inria.fr/). It can translate some [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) like syntax to both PDF and to HTML.

You may also consider using [Docbook](https://docbook.org/). Or [Lout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_(software)). Or [TexInfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) (the prefered format for GNU software).